# Tzniut question

Tags: clothing, tznius-modesty

Where's written/mentioned about redidth (any Jewish sources on this issue please)?

And the second quesiton. Is it a proper way to keep tzniut with wearing redidth if: 
i) a woman live in an secular city/country and such type of dressing may bring just more attention; 
ii) a woman live in an Arab/Muslim region/country and it may look like she's wearing a hijab so locals may mistake her with Muslim woman? (and Jews should look different than non-Jews).

Thanks!

Redidth is something like that:  goo.gl/images/0yEGNM
(It's a type of head covering but if kisui rosh cover hair only, redidth cover neck, head, ears).

Comment: you can start here: http://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.72a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: also in the book : א' גרוסמן חסידות ומורדות – נשים יהודיות באירופה בימי הביניים  he shows the influence the muslim hijab had on jewish women

Comment: I think all your questions are addressed [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30301/3073).